# how to establish 2-way SSL connection from Spring-XD

Tags: ssl, https, client-certificates, spring-xd

I am calling a url over Https which uses 2 way authentication.
Spring XD is able to accept the server's certificate, however the server also needs SpringXD to present authentication.

I have the certificate with me that SpringXD needs to send to server but dont know exactly where I should configure it ?

I am using http-client processor module to establish a connection over HTTPS.

Appreciate if someone can point me to correct configuration.

Below is my stream :
**stream create --name hitSSL --definition "jms --destination=readFromQ | http-client --url='''https://remoteHost:remotePort/trafficcontrol/''' --httpMethod=GET | log"**

And I get this when trying to hit the URL :
**:Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should create the key store file (JKS) using some key tool and place your certificate file there.

After that you should provide `JAVA_OPTS` ENV variable to say `xd-container` shell script to pick up your JKS file:

```
export JAVA_OPTS=-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=mySrvKeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=123456
xd-container
```

or modify `xd-container` script for the `DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS` with the same `-D` options.

No need to do any coding.

Comment: Thanks @Artem. I was able to connect to https url. I edited my xd-admin and xd-container to have :                                                            #Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS="-javaagent:/opt/spring-xd-1.1.0.M1/xd/lib/HostnameVerifier-01.00.00.07.jar -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/prod/mycert/myclientcert.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_24-R28.1.3-4.0.1/jre/lib/security/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.debug=true"